# Should i resize the bitmap before adding to a ImageView or let the ImageView resize the Bitmap?

Tags: android, performance, bitmap, resize, imageview

i have a simple question: Should i resize a bigger bitmap before 
adding to a ImageView or let the ImageView resize the Bitmap? 
What's the right way, regarding performance?

Thanks

Comment: Are you scaling to a fixed pixel size (i.e,. px), or a density/scale independent (i.e. dp/sp) size?

Comment: To dip's. I've forgotten to say that the Bitmap is only a little bit bigger than the ImageViews height/width, about 10%.

Comment: If it's only a little bit bigger, just use `setScaleType`. If it were an order of magnitude bigger, I'd recommend scaling down during/after loading and discarding the original.

Comment: Ok, i've just tested it. The images (loaded from web, 134px*134px) are optimized for a 240dpi density. So on 240dpi devices the image will not be scaled, it is perfect. On 160dpi devices it will be scaled about 66% (89px*89px) and on 120dpi devices 100% (67px*67px). It's not critical, right?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Consider using scale for ImageView, and don't bother about resizing. You can scale an image like this, for example:

```
image.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
image.setMaxHeight(50);
image.setMaxWidth(50);
image.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE);
```

Comment: If the image was 1000 x 1000, and you wanted it 50x50, is this really the best way? Seems inefficient to me.

Comment: well if you crop the image or resize it you might loose it's quality so scaling is the best way to do it and keep the quality high.

Answer (score 1):

The bigger the image, the bigger the size, I wouldn't think performance would really be affected but keep things efficient.

You could also place different size images in the different folders for different resolutions:

```
res/drawable-mdpi/my_icon.png        // bitmap for medium density
res/drawable-hdpi/my_icon.png        // bitmap for high density
res/drawable-xhdpi/my_icon.png       // bitmap for extra high density
```

[Supporting different size screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)

Answer (score 1):

we can resize the existing bitmap to any size using bitmap.createScaledBitmap use the below code.

```
bmp=Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bmp,destBitmapWith, destBitmapHeight,true);
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for as BitmapFactory returns immutable bitmaps.

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this:

```
ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        imageView.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
        imageView.setMaxHeight(imageView.getHeight());
        imageView.setMaxWidth(imageView.getWidth());
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE);
        imageView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath));
```